# Android: Epub file not showing images in emulator/android device

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator, epub

I am using http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib to read epub file. My code is mentioned below.

```
try {
    book = epubReader.readEpub(new FileInputStream("/sdcard/EpubTesting.epub"));

        Resource res;
        Spine contents = book.getSpine();

        List<SpineReference> spinelist  =  contents.getSpineReferences();
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        int count = spinelist.size();


         for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
            res = contents.getResource(i);
            try {
            InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      linez = (string.append(line+"\n")).toString();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         }


         System.out.println(linez);
         s1.loadDataWithBaseURL("/sdcard/",linez, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "File not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "IO Exception.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Also tried

```
s1.loadDataWithBaseURL("",linez, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
s1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://mnt/sdcard/",linez, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

But result is sifar. Please tell me what I have to do to show the contained images in file. I have gone through FAQ says Make a subclass of `android.webkit.WebView` that overloads the `loadUrl(String)` method in such a way that it loads the image from the Book instead of the internet. But till I don't where they extract the file how can I locate the path. Please tell me. I am very confused. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

```
public class EpubBookContentActivity extends Activity{

private static final String TAG = "EpubBookContentActivity";
WebView webview;

Book book;

int position = 0;

String line;
int i = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files;

    try {

        files = assetManager.list("books");
        List<String> list =Arrays.asList(files);

        if (!this.makeDirectory("books")) {
            debug("faild to make books directory");
        }

        copyBookToDevice(list.get(position));

        String basePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/books/";

        InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager.open("books/"+list.get(position));

        book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);

        DownloadResource(basePath);

        String linez = "";
        Spine spine = book.getSpine(); 
        List<SpineReference> spineList = spine.getSpineReferences() ;
        int count = spineList.size();

        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; count > i; i++) {

            Resource res = spine.getResource(i);

            try {
                InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        linez =   string.append(line + "\n").toString();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        linez = linez.replace("../", "");

//            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test.html");
//            file.createNewFile();
//            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
//            fileOutputStream.write(linez.getBytes());
//            fileOutputStream.close();


        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/books/", linez, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("epublib exception", e.getMessage());
    } 
}

public boolean makeDirectory(String dirName) {
    boolean res;        

    String filePath = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+dirName);

    debug(filePath);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        res = file.mkdirs();
    }else {
        res = false;        
    }
    return res; 
}

public void debug(String msg) {
    //      if (Setting.isDebug()) {
    Log.d("EPub", msg);
    //      }
}

public void copyBookToDevice(String fileName) {     
    System.out.println("Copy Book to donwload folder in phone");
    try
    {
        InputStream localInputStream = getAssets().open("books/"+fileName);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/books/"+fileName;
        FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);

        byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
        int offset;
        while ((offset = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte))>0)
        {
            localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, offset);                  
        }
        localFileOutputStream.close();
        localInputStream.close();
        Log.d(TAG, fileName+" copied to phone");   

    }
    catch (IOException localIOException)
    {
        localIOException.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "failed to copy");
        return;
    }
}



private void DownloadResource(String directory) {
    try {

        Resources rst = book.getResources();
        Collection<Resource> clrst = rst.getAll();
        Iterator<Resource> itr = clrst.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Resource rs = itr.next();

            if ((rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.JPG)
                                            || (rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.PNG)
                                            || (rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.GIF)) {

                Log.d(TAG, rs.getHref());

                File oppath1 = new File(directory, rs.getHref().replace("OEBPS/", ""));    

                oppath1.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                oppath1.createNewFile();

                System.out.println("Path : "+oppath1.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());


                FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(oppath1);
                fos1.write(rs.getData());
                fos1.close();

            } else if (rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.CSS) {

                File oppath = new File(directory, rs.getHref());

                oppath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                oppath.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(oppath);
                fos.write(rs.getData());
                fos.close();

            }

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Kirti, its a nice demo. Thanks. But here is one issue that images are not showing. Do you have any update on this issue?

Comment: css & images are downloaded into storage/sdcard0/books/images & ..same path/css but not showing on screen. css has been applied successfully. Issue with images only

Comment: Store book data to file.just remove comment in my code. and place the images and test.html file in same folder and check the issue

Comment: in test.html check the path of img src.

Comment: path for image is "images/epubbooks-logo.png". and also checked test.html. working fine with images

Comment: @KiritVaghela Hey I am unable to make directory books. Its going in debug method. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @ Kirit Vaghela . Very good .Thanks.Mr @ Prathamesh Talathi your error is form manifest you should add this (<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />) in your manifest.xml .Else the response @ Kirit Vaghela is correct .

Comment: Do we really need to save the images and styles to external storage? Can't we directly access them?

Answer (score 3):

For that you have to download all resources of epub files (i.e. images,stylesheet) in location where you downloaded .epub file in sdcard. please check below code to download images and css files from .epub files itself using epublib.
for that u have to send parameter of File objects where you want to store those images.

```
private void DownloadResource(File FileObj,String filename) {
  try {
   InputStream epubis = new FileInputStream(FileObj);
   book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubis);

   Resources rst = book.getResources();
   Collection<Resource> clrst = rst.getAll();
   Iterator<Resource> itr = clrst.iterator();

   while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Resource rs = itr.next();

    if ((rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.JPG)
      || (rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.PNG)
      || (rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.GIF)) {
     File oppath1 = new File(directory, "Images/"
       + rs.getHref().replace("Images/", ""));

     oppath1.getParentFile().mkdirs();
     oppath1.createNewFile();

     FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(oppath1);
     fos1.write(rs.getData());
     fos1.close();

    } else if (rs.getMediaType() == MediatypeService.CSS) {
     File oppath = new File(directory, "Styles/"
       + rs.getHref().replace("Styles/", ""));

     oppath.getParentFile().mkdirs();
     oppath.createNewFile();

     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(oppath);
     fos.write(rs.getData());
     fos.close();

    }

   }


  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.v("error", e.getMessage());
  }
 }
```

after this use this your code to set path of images in webview.
if stored in sd card then

```
s1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/",linez, "text/html",null,null);
```

or

```
s1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://mnt/sdcard/",linez, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

if in internal storage then

```
s1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///data/data/com.example.project/app_mydownload/",linez, "text/html",null,null);
```